# Why does my Python function return None even when I put return?

Tags: python

This was a question on my test and I got it incorrect. When I put it in Python the output is None. I don't understand why so it would be great if someone could explain that to me.

```
def multiply(s,t):
    t*=s
    return
def main():
    d=multiply(2,3)
    print(d)
main()
```

Comment: Need `return t`.  The default return is None.  Or even simpler `return s*t` and delete the line above the return.

Comment: @DarrylG what about this question? 
Write the output of the following program:

```
x = 4
y = 2*x
for y in range(x):
    y-=2
print(y)
```

Comment: @elmo--assuming I entered it correctly I get: `-2
-1
0
1` (all on separate lines) .  This is because y at the beginning of each loop will be 0, 1, 2 or 3 (regardless of assignments inside the loop).  Inside the loop we subtract 2 and print the result creating the output mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything, therefore output of function is None. If you want to return multiply of given integers you can do this like below:

```
def multiply(s,t):
    return t*s

def main():
    d=multiply(2,3)
    print(d)

main()
```